Ubuntu server not responding after few days
I would like know if anyone else has had this problem. I have my own device as a server with Ubuntu Server operating system in the server room. After some time the server always stops responding to ping while the server is still running. I have to restart it and then everything runs fine again for some time.
I have tried this even on a clean Ubuntu server without any other services. I have gone through the logs but found no problem in them. I would still like to try setting the ip to static to avoid the problem from DHCP.
Update: So today I was at the server and found the pc running. The network card is communicating. No signal after connecting the VGA. The disk light wasn't even on. The fans were spinning the computer can only be turned off hard. I think the fault might be more in the HW but where?

stops responding to ping? Only ping no response? Lost IP? IP changed? Is the IP still the same? At this time, manual renew DHCP still fails?  Did the fan of this machine stop at this time??  Does the NIC  enter power saving mode? You'd better describe the situation in more detail.

No services are running. Ping returns Destination host unreachable. How can I find out if the IP has changed? After a reboot, the correct one is there. When I come in the network card is still communicating so it shouldn't be in NIC mode. Thank you very much for the answers

It is unclear, but if your are using DHCP, did you see a changed IP on server's log ? What kind of device is the DHCP server ? also are you using IPV4 or IPV6 ?

"I have my own device as a server with Ubuntu Server operating system in the server room" - can you log on to the server's console? (Either physically or by using a KVM.) That will let you look at its state, and in particular its network addresses and default route. From there you can decide how best to address whatever problem it is that's manifested

Can you configure the DHCP server?   Is it possible to set a static IP address on DHCP for this machine first to avoid DHCP issues?   Or set a static IP directly on this machine.

If this problem occurs regularly, have you checked the processes in crontab?

I asked the administrator he said that supposedly the IP is assigned by the DHCP server using the MAC address.

How many NICs (including WiFi) do your machines have?
Are all of these NIC connected to the Internet/LAN?
Does every NIC have it's own default gateway?
If you have more then one NIC(include WiFi), and connect to LAN/Internet,
You had better choose one of them as default NIC with single default gateway.
Yes, delete the others NIC's default gateway!
But you can add the LAN router on the others, so they still can connect to LAN , and other LAN IP can connect to it, too.
I once used NB to build a proxy server in China, inside the holy GFW.
One network line must be connected to the internal LAN and the other one, via USB LAN dongle, dedicated to the outside Internet.
So, the default router can only be set for the outside Internet.
For the internal LAN, added a net router by manually.
General speaking, route -n or route print just  ONE 'default gateway', no matter how many NIC you have.
Try to save these shell script code on your machine, and run it
It will try to record the time you disconnect
#!/bin/bash
## File: rwx--x--x ping.sh

## Default GW
TestIP=192.168.240.1
LogFile=/tmp/ping.log

while true; do
  ping -n 1 ${TestIP} > /dev/null
  res=$?
  if [ ${res} -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo `date` : IP=${TestIP} Ping FAIL
    echo `date` : IP=${TestIP} Ping FAIL >> ${LogFile}
    printf "\07"
  fi
  sleep 59
done


I only have one network card connected to my device. The server is with the internet provider. So I have the time of the last DHCP and ARP. I tried to look for these times in the system log but nothing came up. The server has been running for the longest time 3 months now it crashes about once a week.

@Mydo try to run the shell script above to record the fail time. Find out the regularity of failure time first. maybe you can log the router/IP/ps/..etc. at failure time .

The ring bell, by printf, is only valid for on-site terminals. Because your network is disconnected, it is impossible to SEE the ring character from the remote end.

I'm going there today to try and run this script on the using screen thanks

So today I was at the server and found the pc running. The network card is communicating. No signal after connecting the VGA. The disk light wasn't even on. The fans were spinning the computer can only be turned off hard. I think the fault might be more in the HW but where?
